# What function should I use to truncate a string?

Tags: 5

What function should I use to truncate a string in Drupal 5?

Answer (score 3):

[truncate_utf8()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--unicode.inc/function/truncate_utf8/5) is present in all Drupal versions; just check that the parameters are the same.